# Angular6 - Animation when change value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web

I searched on Google how to do what I want to do and tried some things but nothing works and I found a lot of AngularJS tutorial but not Angular6.. so I hope u will be able to help me.

I want to make a fade when my array's values change (on click) so I downloaded ng-animate but it doesn't give me the behaviour I'm looking for.
Currently, I've got two components so the first:

HTML:

```
 <div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px 0">
      <div class="buttonSelector" *ngFor="let select of buttonSelector" (click)="getSelectArray(select.title)"
           [ngClass]="{'selected': select.title === selectedArray.title.toUpperCase() }">
        <p>{{ select.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <app-infoapp [selectedArray]="selectedArray"></app-infoapp>
```

There, I change my selectedArray by sending a variable to getSelectArray() then I send it to my 'app-infoapp' component.
On my 'app-infoapp' component, we can find this:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';
import {bounce, fadeIn} from 'ng-animate';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infoapp',
  templateUrl: './infoapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./infoapp.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(fadeIn, {delay: 0.2}))])
  ]
})
export class InfoappComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() selectedArray;
  fade: any;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

So now when I refresh my page, the component is fading so that's cool but when I change my array by clicking on the button so another array is sent to my 'app-infoapp' component, it doesn't animate another time.

I hope I was clear and that u will be able to help me.

If you need more informations or if I wasn't clear tell me, I'll answer as fast as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Angular 2 comes with its own animation module as '"@angular/animations' and you can find many great tutorials on that and implement the fade in animation with opacity changes. For example: https://www.kdechant.com/blog/angular-animations-fade-in-and-fade-out

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I tried to follow the tutorial but i've got the same problem: the animation is well visible when I reload the page but when I change the value of my sent array by clicking on my button, it doesn't animate a second time :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same example which i suggested to you (kdechant.com/blog/angular-animations-fade-in-and-fade-out) with your sample code and it is working:

Import BrowserAnimationsModule in the application module (app.module.ts):

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

parent.component.html

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px 0">
  <div *ngFor="let select of buttonSelector" (click)="getSelectArray(select.title)">
    <p>{{ select.title }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<app-infoapp [selectedArray]="selectedArray"></app-infoapp>
```

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public buttonSelector = [];
  public selectedArray = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonSelector = [{title: 'save'}, {title: 'add'}, {title: 'edit'}, {title: 'delete'}];
  }

  getSelectArray(title: string) {
    this.selectedArray.push({title:title});
  }

}
```

info-app.component.html

```
<div class="info" *ngFor="let selected of selectedArray" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
    {{ selected.title }}
</div>
```

info-app.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, state, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infoapp',
  templateUrl: './info-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('simpleFadeAnimation', [
      state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({opacity: 0}),
        animate(600 )
      ]),
      transition(':leave',
        animate(600, style({opacity: 0})))
    ])
  ]
})
export class InfoAppComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() selectedArray = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: I created a stackblitz for your answer. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-on-array-item-addition